# Ограничения доступа к сайту

Tags: php

как сделать чтобы к страницу на сайте мог зайти только некоторые люди?

Comment: сделать регистрацию)

Comment: По IP/Сессии/Куки/HTP и множество других вариантов. Можете более конкретно поставить вопрос? Для чего вам это надо и какие цели вы преследуете

Comment: Чётко определить, кто такие "некоторые люди", и написать в коде сайта проверку, является ли пришедший человек "некоторым" или нет.

Comment: Можно сделать запрос пароля при входе на сайт, не?

Comment: Чтобы на сайт могли заходить только с определенных IP адресов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

/**
 * @author admin
 * @copyright 2019
 */
//список ип адресов
$bd_ip = array(
    'ip1',
    'ip2'   
);
//текущий ип пользователя
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//проверяем если ли ип в списке, если есть - выводим нужный контент
if (in_array($ip, $bd_ip)) {
    echo 'нужный контент';
}

?>
```